# Swift: Collection View changing layout after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with 6 items and want to display them in a 2 cells per row and 3 rows format. The following code achieves this (as taken from this question: [Swift: Collection View not adjusting correctly to change in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228821/swift-collection-view-not-adjusting-correctly-to-change-in-size)) in iPhone format nicely.

However on the any iPad the views layout is correct initially but if the screen is rotated to landscape and then back to portrait then the layout does not fully fit within the view and requires  horizontal scrolling to see the second cell (cells width has somehow increased meaning the second cell in each row is partially cut off).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 collectionView.dataSource = self
 collectionView.delegate = self

 flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
 flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
 flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 6
}


override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

     if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        let totalWidth = collectionView.frame.width 
        let totalHeight = collectionView.frame.height 

        let heightOfCell = totalHeight / 2
        let numberOfCellsPerRow = 1
        let widthOfCell = CGFloat(Int(totalWidth) / numberOfCellsPerRow)

        return CGSize(width: widthOfCell , height: heightOfCell)

    } else {
        let totalWidth = collectionView.frame.width 
        let totalHeight = collectionView.frame.height 
        let heightOfCell = (totalHeight / 3)

        let numberOfCellsPerRow = 2
        let widthOfCell = CGFloat(Int(totalWidth) / numberOfCellsPerRow)

        return CGSize(width: widthOfCell , height: heightOfCell)
    }
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
}
```

[image: Before rotation]
[image: After rotation]

Comment: I can't recreate your problem - I've tried copying and pasting your exact code and when I rotate portrait -> landscape -> portrait, it is exactly the same as it started. Can you maybe show some screenshots to illustrate more clearly what's happening?

Comment: I've added them, this is only happening on the iPad, not iPhone

Comment: Have you adjusted anything on the storyboard? This isn't the layout I get after adding a brand new collection view to my scene with your code.

Comment: I left out the insetForSectionAt function which I have now added. Could you show me what yours looks like?

Comment: So mine looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/ZIV0z - obviously you can ignore the styling, I've just set the cell to have a black background in `cellForItemAt`. In the storyboard, the collection view has constraints of 0 to all edges of the view.

Comment: And you are not getting an issue of the cell width increasing after rotation on the iPad?

Comment: Well the cell width increases for the landscape view, but then it changes back as expected when going back to portrait.

Comment: Yeah at the moment mine changes with landscape but is then larger than the original portrait when going back to portrait. I've added a photo of the collectionView traits in the storyboard as well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/51n3n.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be that, frame of the view is not updated when 'willRotate' is invoked. Instead try 'didrotate' or add the observer 'NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange' and invalidateLayout of collection inside the selector method. Don't forget to remove the observer on deinit().

Comment: As far as I remember you dont use those methods anymore you use viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)